# dynamic expression with @identifier

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a situation where  i have to generate conditions dynamically in LINQ 
for every other column i could do, but for this one

```
p=>p.default
```

here **default** is a key word(Sql Sever)
 I have to generate like this

```
p=>p.@default
```

**How do i generate this dynamically?** 
this is how i generate for other columns

```
var paramexp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
var proprty = typeof(T).GetProperty(columnName);
Expression.Property(paramexp, proprty)
```

Comment: Do you mean `p => p.@default`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the property by string without the `@` sign:

```
var proprty = typeof(T).GetProperty("default");
```

The `@` sign is only necessary for the compiler to distinguish between a name and a reserved word.

Comment: This is all correct. I just wrote a property called `default`, written `@default` in C#, and the property is found with `GetProperty("default")` while `GetProperty("@default")` finds nothing (gives `null`). Of course the `@` is not part of the real name. I looked at the IL with _IL DASM_ and they write the name in single quotes `'default'` which they don't do for other properties. However `GetProperty("'default'")` doesn't find the property.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `GetProperty("'default'")` to work - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: i had same code as you mentioned , because of a stupid issue ,it did not work,anyway thanks